# HTML Bootstrap Grid Layout Horizontal

Tags: html

I am trying align it so that it will be tests as heading, then gibberish 1, 2, 3 on same row under it. i don't know what I'm doing wrong. right now it only shows as gibberish 1 under it on the left. can someone please help me out?

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row" id="tests">
                <div class="test col-md-12">
                    <h2>tests</h2><br>
                        <ul class="col-md-4">
                            <li>
                                gibberish 1
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                gibberish 1
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                gibberish 1
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                gibberish 1
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="col-md-4">
                            <li>
                                gibberish 2
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="col-md-4">
                            <li>
                               gibberish 3
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: wrap each ul inside a separate div. 3 ul, 3 div. Now, take the class name col-md-4 and make it class name of div instead of ul.

Comment: I tried that for some reason it didn't work. you mean something like  div(col-md-4 )-ul-li-"gibberish1-li-ul-div  div(col-md-4 )-ul-li-"gibberish2-li-ul-div ?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your `ul` on one div with class name `row` like

```
<div class="row">
   <ul class="col-md-4">
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


I am trying align it so that it will be tests as heading, then gibberish 1, 2, 3 on same row under it. i don't know what I'm doing wrong. right now it only shows as gibberish 1 under it on the left. can someone please help me out?

<div class="container">
            <div class="row" id="tests">
                <div class="test col-md-12">
                    <h2>tests</h2><br>
                    <div class="row"><!-- Add This -->
                        <ul class="col-md-4">
                            <li>
                                gibberish 1
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                gibberish 1
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                gibberish 1
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                gibberish 1
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="col-md-4">
                            <li>
                                gibberish 2
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="col-md-4">
                            <li>
                               gibberish 3
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                     </div> <!-- Add This -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```